# How to get response from one promise in two different methods in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I need to do some changes to a legacy AngularJS application.

I have two methods in a controller:

```
const params: any = {id: 1};
public getGridData(): void {
  this.dataService.getPanelData(params).then((response: any) => {
     const dataToBeUsedInGrid = response.data.locationDetails;
     // extra code
  }
}

public getMapData() : void {
  this.dataService.getPanelData(params).then((response: any) => {
     const dataToBeUsedInMap = response.data.locationDetails.Coordinates;
     // extra code
  }
}
```

And this is the code in dataService which is just making an api call:

```
public getPanelData(params: any) {
        return this.$http.post(this.dataConfigService.url, params);
    }
```

Now this code is making two api calls. I just make to make one api call to server and use the response in different places as the response is same in both the calls.
Both the getGridData and getMapData methods are called together asynchronously upon a record selection, and are responsible for displaying different data on the same page.

Comment: Why do you need two functions? You can merge both function bodies to `getData`.

Comment: You can call `then` multiple times on the same promise, or `await` the same promise multiple times if it makes a difference. In other words, if you have a promise for one call to the API, you can extract different parts of the response in different parts of the code using the same promise. However, the existing controller does not require `params` to be the same for calls to `getGridData` and `getMapData`. You need to ensure `params` doesn't change between calls to them before amalgamating calls to the API into a single call.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually a simple solution would be to refactor the code (functions) that call `getGridData` and `getMapData` into functions that are passed the data they need to update the page as an argument. Call the modified functions `handleGridData` and `handleMapData` for now.

Now refactor record selection to call `getPanelData`, then `handleGridData`, and then `handleMapData` in the asynchronous coding style of your choice. If you use `async` functions and the `await` operator you can probably in-line the code for the proposed handler functions, as well as handling errors gracefully.